# Rebind keys depending on the program with focus

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

I want to do [How to map a key to another on my keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130144/how-to-map-a-key-to-another-on-my-keyboard) but have different mappings for different programs.

Specifically, I want to map the F6 key to F7 whenever a specific window has the focus.

I use xUbuntu 14.04 if that makes a difference.

Comment: you can use AutoKey for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using xdotool**

I don't think there's any DE that has an inbuilt option for this, but with the help of [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) we can write a custom script that should do the trick:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# 'f6f7swap.sh' by Glutanimate
# 
# Reassign F6 to F7 if specific application has focus
# Dependencies: xdotool x11-utils
# 
# Usage:    f6f7swap.sh '<full window class>'
# Example:  f6f7swap.sh '"gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"'

# --Variables--

WinClass="$1"

# --Main--

# get currently active window ID
ActiveWinID="$(xdotool getactivewindow)"
# get window class of active window
ActiveWmClass="$(xprop -id "$ActiveWinID" \
  | grep "WM_CLASS" \
  | awk -F' = ' '{print $2}' )"

# Compare with provided window class
if [[ "$ActiveWmClass" = "$WinClass" ]]; then
  echo "Target window found. Sending 'F7'"
  xdotool key F7
else
  echo "Target window not found. Sending 'F6'"
  xdotool key F6
fi
```

**Instructions**

1. Make sure you have `xdotool` and `xprop` installed (`sudo apt-get install xdotool x11-utils`)
2. Save this script as `f6f7swap.sh` and make it executable
3. Determine the window class of your target window/application by running `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` and clicking on a sample window
4. Run `f6f7swap.sh` with the full window class as an argument, e.g.:

   ```
   f6f7swap.sh '"gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"'
   ```

   `f6f7swap.sh` will try to match the active window with the provided window class. If they match the script will send 'F7'; if not it will send'F6'.
5. Bind the full command (e.g. `f6f7swap.sh '"gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"'`) to <kbd>F6</kbd> in your keyboard preferences

---

**Updated script**

The following is a more generic version of the script that allows swapping out any key of your choice:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# 'keyswap.sh' by Glutanimate
# 
# Reassign keys if specific application has focus
# Dependencies: xdotool
# 
# Usage:    keyswap.sh '<full window class>' '<input key>' '<output key>'
# Example:  keyswap.sh '"gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"' 'F6' 'F7'

# --Variables and Checks--

Usage="Usage: keyswap.sh '<full window class>' '<input key>' '<output key>'"

if [[ "$#" != "3" ]]; then
  echo "Error: Insufficient arguments"
  echo "$Usage"
  exit 1
fi

WinClass="$1"
OrigKey="$2"
ReplKey="$3"

# --Main--

# get currently active window ID
ActiveWinID="$(xdotool getactivewindow)"
# get window class of active window
ActiveWmClass="$(xprop -id "$ActiveWinID" \
  | grep "WM_CLASS" \
  | awk -F' = ' '{print $2}' )"

# Compare with provided window class
if [[ "$ActiveWmClass" = "$WinClass" ]]; then
  echo "Target window found. Sending $ReplKey"
  xdotool key "$ReplKey"
else
  echo "Target window not found. Sending $OrigKey"
  xdotool key "$OrigKey"
fi
```

Invoke it with:

```
keyswap.sh '<full window class>' '<input key>' '<output key>'
```

E.g.:

```
keyswap.sh '"gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"' 'F6' 'F7'
```