# How can I map right-Ctrl to Fn?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I use the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys frequently. (Seems most people don't use these keys much anymore.) Unfortunately, because it's such a small computer, Dell put <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> on top of the left and right arrow keys, requiring holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key down to get <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

There's a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key right next to the cursor keys. I never use this key, as I have <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I'd like it to behave as a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key so I can press <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> (<kbd>Home</kbd>) and <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> (<kbd>End</kbd>) using one hand.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: I ran both showkey and xev, as suggested by @A.B.'s comment, and the Fn key does not trigger any output. I have a feeling that means my request is impossible.

[image]

Comment: does this solve your problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/137758/294611

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo showkey` and press your `Fn` key. Is there an output for the `Fn` key? If not start `xev` and press `Fn` and add the output into your question.

Comment: @A.B.  (question edited) Neither program could see Fn key presses.

Comment: This is a hardware issue and generally impossible, though there may be a model or two out there that allows it. Even so, it would require something beyond software keybinding.

Comment: Start the same commands as described in my comment above and now use `Fn-Home` and `Fn-End` to check the key codes.

Comment: @A.B.  Hmm, showkey says keycodes are 102 and 107 (Fn-Home and Fn-End), while xev says 110 and 115.

Comment: No problem. Now I can write a positive answer for you.

Comment: Start `xbindkeys -k` and press `RightCtrl-Left`. Start `xbindkeys -k` again and start `RightCtrl-Right` and give me the output please.

Comment: @A.B.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x4 + c:113
    Control + Left

"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x4 + c:114
    Control + Right

Comment: We have a problem, I can't distinguish between Control_L and Control_R both have the modifier `0x4` (`m:0x4`)

Answer (score 4):

Install `xautomation`, we need the command `xte`

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

and `xbindkeys`

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Create or edit the file `~/.xbindkeysrc`

```
nano ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

and add the following lines

```
"xte 'key Home'"
 m:0x4 + c:113

"xte 'key End'"
 m:0x4 + c:114
```

Test with

```
killall xbindkeys
xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

The package `xbindkeys` installs a autostart entry

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/xbindkeys.desktop
```

No further things are necessary.

Comment: Great way to work around the problem!

Comment: Hmm, I followed these instructions to a tee and everything seemed to go ok, but...  it's not working for me. Other than trying right-control-right-arrow (hoping for End), is there any way to check that I've set everything up according to your answer?

Comment: Are this exact the same values, which you get with `xbindkeys -k`?

Comment: @A.B. Yes   "(Scheme function)" m:0x4 + c:113 Control + Left "(Scheme function)" m:0x4 + c:114 Control + Right

Comment: To the upvoters: This worked on your Dell XPS running Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Welp, apparently this is a useful answer even if it didn't work for me. Bounty awarded. Thanks @A.B.

Comment: I'm sorry :\ I will check this in the next days again. Perhaps, but that's only an idea, we can change the modifier for the right Ctrl key.

Comment: And it's good, that you haven't accepted the answer. A not working answer can't be an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> is a dead key: that means all by itself, it doesn't have a scan code and only gives an additional scan code to other keys when pressed together with them.

You can see this when you go to `tty1` and executing there:

```
showkey --keycodes
```

Any key you press will give you an output, *except* <kbd>Fn</kbd>, so mapping <kbd>Fn</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is impossible.

However, *depending on the hardware of your keyboard*, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> *could* be mapped to E.G. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> but then you'd lose the functionality of both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys...

<sub>(I tried it on my keyboard and there it's impossible as <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> give the same scancodes...)</sub>

Comment: This was my suspicion, that Fn is a dead key. What  do you make of the other (upvoted) answers?

Comment: A.B. always uses black magic that's beyond me: I only do white magic, so I would say: that's the best answer...  However, I thought of something: If you're willing to give up `word left` and `word right` (what is now in [Ctrl]← and [Ctrl]→) *that* might work... (update answer?)

Comment: I use word-left and word-right a lot, so that wouldn't work for me. Someone else though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler solution: bind `sh -c "xdotool getactivewindow key Home "` and `sh -c "xdotool getactivewindow key End "` commands, to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Of course you need to install `xdotool` first with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`.

Then go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> -> <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> -> <kbd>Custom</kbd>. Click the plus button and create new shortcuts.

Note: You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow_Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow_Down</kbd>,but I wouldn't recommend that or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key , as some programs use those as shortcuts already. For instance [firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) uses those.